# TRUNCATE TABLE in MySQL 8 takes 10 seconds or more even when the table is empty

Tags: mysql, database

Is there any issue about MySQL that it takes so many seconds to drop even an empty table.

MySQL version: 8.0.23 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Some info:

- I'm running Postgres at the same machine (local dev). I have stopped Postgres already but nothing.
- I realized about the issue when testing a Ruby on Rails application. The database have several tables and, for each table, it takes an average of 7 seconds to truncate each one.
- So I went to MySQL client and could see that, in fact, it really takes a bunch of seconds to get a single table truncated.

Is that a problem of having Postgres and MySQL installed at the same machine?

I didn't find anything useful to solve the issue.

Comment: Are you running queries against the table at the time you want to truncate it? The delay could be waiting for a metadata lock.

Comment: No, I'm not @BillKarwin. Only doing `TRUNCATE TABLE`.

Comment: Have you found any solution?